# Pytesseract confused between Zero ('0') and the Capital O ('O')

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm using Python-based OCR (Pytesseract) to read images as part of PDFs to extract certain ISIN values out of it. In some cases, the OCR algorithms read zero (0) as the letter "O".

The output i get is:

```
IEOOBQZJ1775 mULeyN USD Unhedged Accumulation
```

The expected output is:

```
IE00BQZJ1775 mULeyN USD Unhedged Accumulation
```

The block of code responsible for this is:

```
import pytesseract 
from PIL import Image
import cv2

img = Image.open('out.jpg')
new_image = cv2.bitwise_not(img)
new_image = cv2.resize(new_image, (0,0), fx=1.5, fy=1.5)


target = pytesseract.image_to_string(new_image, lang='eng', config='--psm 7 --oem 3')
```

I have tried different --oem along with different --psm but the problem still pertains. Any insight shall be immensely helpful. Anything via image-preprocessing via Opencv that might help in detection.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like tesseract isn’t at all ‘confused’ because it seems certain those are zeros, however disappointed you are by the results - maybe you can get it to work if you provide text in a font which has a clearer difference between the two characters?

Comment: Apparently that's not an option as the font is extracted through the PDF form. @barny

Comment: Two ideas. If letter "O" never occurs, then you can always `replace` it in the returned string. If letter "O" *or* number 0 can occur *and* you have very high quality images, you might be able to use [template matching](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html) to replace number 0 with a more recognizable zero. The run the modified image through pytesseract.

Comment: Replacing the string shouldn't be a solution as there could be situation where they both may coexist. Template matching could be a solution, though far fetched, i was wondering if there's any tweak via OpenCV which might make the charterers more readable to the OCR engine. Thanks for the input though. @bfris

Comment: All this fuss about 0 and O, what about I and l? That’s capital eye and lowercase ell.

Answer (score 2):

For the ISIN, may be you can make use of its structure to verify its validity. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Securities_Identification_Number) page, ISIN consists of

- two alphabetic characters for the issuing country
- nine alpha-numeric character NSIN, padded as necessary with leading zeros
- one numerical check digit calculated using the 'Luhn algorithm'

At least, with the check digit we can say whether the OCR succeeded or not, and possibly correct it. Of course, tesseract might get certain characters wrong, including the check digit, so, maybe you can get the confidence level (if it's there, I haven't used tesseract in years) for each character to get an idea about its accuracy.

If you want to do image processing, for 0 and O, you can fit an ellipse and check the eccentricity, but it depends on the font.

Comment: Of course there is a structure which can be verified and the structure as you mentioned has 9 alpha-numeric character NSIN that can have both the letter O and the digit 0. Hence both the cases, when detected zero or O, the pattern will be verified, but the accurate detection of a particular character is a problem, which by the way, is a long standing challenge between Zero and O when it comes to OCR.

Comment: @AnitChakraborty I thought your question was about ISIN. If it is about this so called long standing ocr ambiguity, then this answer does not help.